# Sql Query results to CSV to a specified file path after stored procedure execution

Tags: sql, csv, directory, export

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure (which i know works) in T-SQL that then gets those results into a CSV file and puts that file into a directory.  I'm not sure how to formulate that query, exactly though.  Here's what i've tried thus far to no avail:

```
EXECUTE CLR_ExportQueryToCSV @QueryCommand = 'execute databaseName.dbo.StoredProcedureName',
                          @FilePath = 'C:\Directory',
                          @FileName = '\FileToExport.csv',
                          @IncludeHeaders = 1
```

I realize CLR_ExportQueryToCSV doesn't exist.  Is there any system stored procedure that will do what i'm wanting?

Comment: Maybe create a DTS package?

Answer (score 5):

```
bcp "SELECT Col1,Col2,Col3 FROM MyDatabase.dbo.MyTable" queryout "D:\MyTable.csv" -c -t , -S SERVERNAME -T
```

[docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility)

Comment: In the end i realized i could do the above statement without issue.  Thanks for the advice!  Note: the query results will go to the local drive of the SERVER where SQL is running.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there's no generic/supported method in SQL Server to do what you're asking.

If you're simply looking for a way to dump the results of a SQL query to CSV then I'd be more inclined to either write an SSIS package to do the job or a C# console app, either of which can be scheduled.

Here's an example in C#:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    WriteQueryResultsToCsv(@"c:\SqlResults.csv", 
        "MyDbConnectionStringName", 
        "select * from MyTable where x > @x",
        new SqlParameter("@x", SqlDbType.Int) {Value = 1});
}

private static void WriteQueryResultsToCsv(string csvPath, string connectionStringName, string sql, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    // Requires reference to System.Configuration
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName].ConnectionString;

    using (var db = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, db))
    {
        db.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

        using (var dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        using (var dw = new StreamWriter(csvPath))
        using (var csv = new CsvWriter(dw)) // Requires CsvHelper package from NuGet
        {
            // Write column headers
            for (var c = 0; c < dr.FieldCount; c++)
                csv.WriteField(dr.GetName(c));

            // Write data rows
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                csv.NextRecord();
                for (var c = 0; c < dr.FieldCount; c++)
                {
                    csv.WriteField(dr.GetValue(c).ToString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  I've been able to write this functionality using C# plenty of times but i was specifically tasked with doing it by a Sql Server Agent job, instead of writing any C# code.  Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Invoking CMD is one way to achieve it and can automate it

```
Declare @sql VARCHAR(max)
declare @CsvFile NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(4000) 
set @sql = 'Exec [dbo].[Usp_CSVextract]'
set @CsvFile = 'C:\Test.csv'
SET @cmd = 
'bcp '+CHAR(34)+@sql+CHAR(34)+' queryout '+CHAR(34)+@CsvFile+CHAR(34)+' -S '+@@servername
+' -c -t'+CHAR(34)+','+CHAR(34)+' -r'+CHAR(34)+'\n'+CHAR(34)+' -T'

exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

There *IS* one way of doing what you're asking in SQL, but it's not neat or supported (AFAIK).

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'SQLCMD -S . -d MyDatabase -Q "select * from MyTable" -s "," -o "\\servername\output\result.csv" -W'
```

You can find documentation for SQLCMD [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility), but essentially what this does is use the xp_cmdshell SP to execute the SQLCMD command line utility on the server and execute a sql statement, piping the output to a CSV file.

The params I've used are as follows:

```
-S: SQL Server name - . means current server
-d: database name
-Q: run SQL query and exit
-s: column separator
-o: output file. This is relative to the SQL Server, not your PC
-W: dynamic column witdth
```

By default SQL Server does not allow you to run xp_cmdshell, so you may need to run the following SQL to enable it.

```
-- To allow advanced options to be changed.
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE
GO
-- To enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
GO
-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet I have found is to use a SSIS. Create a Execute SQL Task and run your stored procedure. Then create a data flow set of tasks to move the data from a temporary data table to your CSV file.

Do a search om this web site for how to make a SSIS package. There are a few really nice examples on how to do this.

Good luck to you.

Answer (score 1):

CLR_ExportQueryToCSV is a [clr stored procedure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx) located at [codeplex](http://sqlclrexport.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#CodePlex.vb).

you need to [install project](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1009918/Installing-a-CLR-Stored-Procedure-on-SQL-Server)  at [clr integration enable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/clr-integration-enabling)d sql server